# TinyMCE: buttons does not work after ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce, wicket

I'm using TinyMCE and wicket/jquery requests together.
TinyMCE works fine the first time when it is loaded - every
   buttons work well

Scenario:

- **Given**

  - The page contains a form with fields: rating field and
    textarea (TinyMCE).
- **When**

  - I click rating field to update the field,
- **Then**

  - Wicket updated the field and returns only it (not the whole
    form). And after click on the TinyMCE buttons to change aligns of text
    for instance then nothing happens (BAD!!! the text should apply aligns)

PS: when I click a button in TinyMCE and press ENTER then it starts to apply or menu starts to open.
NB: Remove cache from FF does not work. and it does not work in Chrome as well

What is the strange behavior?

- TinyMCE 4.0.4
- Wicket: 6.9.0
- using jQuery 10.x

  ```
   // *** init tinyMCE ***
  tinymce.baseURL = '/js/tinymce'
  tinymce.suffix = '.min'
  tinymce.init({
      theme: "modern",
      selector:'.tinymce',
      content_css: '/styles/index.css',       
      plugins: [
          "advlist autolink  lists charmap preview hr anchor pagebreak",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking",
          "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
      ],
      toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | preview fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons"
  })
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'found the trouble. it was my mistake. I used stopPropagation on textarea. and it starts to work after removing it.